# Equipment operating on negative voltage instead of positive voltage

Tags: power-supply, power, cellphone, negative

Why do some devices, Carrier grade base stations for WISPs and cell towers for example, operate on a -48v system instead of a +48v system?

A few of our higher end devices operate on a -48v system instead of a +48v system. Why would these companies choose to operate these devices on a negative polarity? are there benefits to this? and to power these devices does your power supply need to specify that it can operate this way?

Comment: The neg Volt approach is better from a wiring corrosion viewpoint.There are similiar questions floating around.

Comment: -48 volts is the traditional telephone service battery voltage, which makes it convenient to use for anything that might be installed in a telephone exchange.